# Bluetooth service fails and freezes after some time in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, bluez

Recently bluetooth is giving a lot of problems in 18.04.5 LTS (I have the latest update), specially when I awake the laptop (I have no TLP installed). I updated bluez and nothing changed. Bluetooth can't connect and does not seem to power on, even after restarting the service.

I find these errors on red when I check the `status` of bluetooth after `restart`:

```
Version mismatch for sixaxis
Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

I also get `Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed` when I try to `power on` on `bluetoothctl`

#### Log

```
$ sudo service bluetooth restart
$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-01-10 14:12:22 CET; 18s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 13873 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─13873 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 10 14:12:22 toshiba systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 10 14:12:22 toshiba bluetoothd[13873]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Jan 10 14:12:22 toshiba systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 10 14:12:22 toshiba bluetoothd[13873]: Starting SDP server
Jan 10 14:12:22 toshiba bluetoothd[13873]: Version mismatch for sixaxis
Jan 10 14:12:22 toshiba bluetoothd[13873]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jan 10 14:12:22 toshiba bluetoothd[13873]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jan 10 14:12:22 toshiba bluetoothd[13873]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jan 10 14:12:24 toshiba bluetoothd[13873]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
Jan 10 14:12:32 toshiba bluetoothd[13873]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)


$ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

```
*-usb:0
  description: Bluetooth wireless interface
  vendor: Intel Corp.
  physical id: 2
  bus info: usb@1:1.2
  version: 0.01
  capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
  configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

#### Note

To make it work again, I need to reboot or restart bluetooth with

```
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

This is really annoying because I'm using it for a bluetooth keyboard, and every time it fails to connect I have to switch to the laptop internal keyboard.

#### output of `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
$ lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b448 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 043e:9a39 LG Electronics USA, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0451:ace1 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    2.908829] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[    2.977750] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.977769] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.977772] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.977774] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.977777] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.076056] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 3707100100012d0d27
[    3.076057] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 27
[    4.525995] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.525997] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.526002] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   21.781694] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   21.781703] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   21.783380] input: Matias Wireless Keyboard (ISO) Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:0250.0005/input/input26
[   21.783901] input: Matias Wireless Keyboard (ISO) Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:0250.0005/input/input27
[   21.784070] input: Matias Wireless Keyboard (ISO) System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:0250.0005/input/input28
[   21.784238] hid-generic 0005:05AC:0250.0005: input,hidraw4: BLUETOOTH HID v0.03 Keyboard [Matias Wireless Keyboard (ISO)] on 34:de:1a:7f:93:1e
[   36.751358] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   36.751364] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   36.751369] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 7147.255880] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0804 tx timeout
[ 7369.683801] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1405 tx timeout
[ 7371.699689] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1403 tx timeout
[ 7373.715640] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c2d tx timeout
[ 7375.731641] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1405 tx timeout
[ 7375.731645] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7377.747576] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1403 tx timeout
[ 7377.747583] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7379.763562] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c2d tx timeout
[ 7379.763566] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7381.779558] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1405 tx timeout
[ 7381.779564] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7383.795496] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1403 tx timeout
[ 7383.795501] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7385.811505] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c2d tx timeout
[ 7385.811514] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7387.827417] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1405 tx timeout
[ 7387.827426] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7389.843348] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1403 tx timeout
[ 7389.843353] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7391.859270] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c2d tx timeout
[ 7391.859275] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7393.875274] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1405 tx timeout
[ 7393.875280] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7395.891263] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1403 tx timeout
[ 7395.891267] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7397.907255] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c2d tx timeout
[ 7397.907262] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7399.923137] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1405 tx timeout
[ 7399.923142] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7401.939191] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1403 tx timeout
[ 7401.939199] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7403.955137] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c2d tx timeout
[ 7403.955144] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7405.971021] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1405 tx timeout
[ 7405.971026] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7407.990996] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1403 tx timeout
[ 7407.991005] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7410.003001] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c2d tx timeout
[ 7410.003006] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7412.018986] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1405 tx timeout
[ 7412.018994] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7414.038911] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1403 tx timeout
[ 7414.038916] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
[ 7416.050860] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c2d tx timeout
[ 7416.050863] Bluetooth: hci0: No way to reset. Ignoring and continuing
```

Comment: Built in Bluetooth or a dongle?

Comment: @David sorry, didn't get it? How do I check that?

Comment: Did you physically put a Bluetooth device in a USB port?

Comment: @David, nope, it's embedded in the laptop

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` to the question.

Comment: @Pilot6 done it, amended accordingly

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: @Pilot6 no, just ubuntu

Comment: I can suggest only to upgrade to a newer kernel. What is the current kernel?

Comment: @Pilot6 how do I know my kernel? Do you mean 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Run `uname -r` in a terminal

Comment: @Pilot6 the result is: `5.4.0-62-generic`

Comment: Try to boot with a previous kernel using grub.

Comment: @Pilot6, sorry, too complex and complicated. For now I reboot the bluetooth service and it works, but it's annoying

Comment: So why ask if you don't want help. There is no magic button.

Comment: What is the model of your Toshiba? I'd like to determine which chipset your Bluetooth module uses as it could be a driver mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Removing and loading `btusb` module helps in some cases:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```